# How do I type right curly (end) bracket in Visual C++ 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like the ability to type right curly brace using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> key combination. This is the combination I use in every other Windows program, but for some reason it doesn't work in Visual C++ 2008. I have the Express version, if that's a relevant fact.

It's funny, because I can type the left curly brace but not the right one. I tried typing it in different locations of the code in text editor, in case this is a relevant factor, but it was all the same. I can't produce the right curly brace. What's going on?...

The only "work-around" I have found is to use <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>. But I am not accustomed to this key combo, and I would like to continue using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> as I have been using it for over 15 years.

Comment: P.S. I've checked my keyboard input language and layout. I know it happens sometimes that I accidentally switch it. But it's all good.

Comment: No one?... really? No idea what this could be? Or how to solve it?

Comment: I have figured it out. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my Swedish fellows, go ahead and find the **View.ViewCode** command in your keyboard options and remove it. That should sort it out.

Here's a short lazy dog (*swe.* [lathund](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lathund)) for you:

1. Tools
2. Options
3. Environment
4. Keyboard
5. Click in the **Press shortcut keys** input field.
6. Press **Ctrl+Alt+0** to reveal what command is using this key combo. It should say **View.ViewCode (Ctrl+Alt+0 (Global))**.
7. Click in the **Show commands containing** input field.
8. Type in the name of the command you see down below, that is **View.ViewCode**.
9. Select this command if not selected already, and click the Remove button down below, where it says **Shortcuts for selected command**.

That should do it. You could also change the key binding to something else. But I found it easier to just remove the damned thing, it doesn't seem to do anything anyway.

I can finally start using Ctrl+Alt+0 instead of AltGr+0. The latter forces me to use one hand instead of two hands, and to place my hand in an unnatural position. Either that, or I would have to move my left hand all the way across the keyboard from the left home (resting) key to the right top key row. Haa haa! Nice joke Microsoft!

[image: visual c++ tools, options, environment, keyboard]

I have not used Visual C++ before so I didn't know what to expect. But I guess they just didn't think about international developers very much back in the days (2008 or so). I'm not sure of the status with the 2010 and 2012 version of Visual C++. But I have not made any customizations yet whatsoever. Well except for this one perhaps... Everything is just default, including the keyboard scheme. I just chose English during install, and I used the offline installer.

**I guess you could say it is faulty by default!!....**

Comment: This was so helpful! This solution worked for me in VS 2015! :)